# How to remove the Segmentation Fault in this code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing the code to solve the Rod Cut problem but I have been getting Segmentation Fault prompts at run-time. I tried to debug this using gdb and it showed the issue with the recRodCut function. Can anyone please help me find the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int recRodCut(int* arr, int n)
{
    int res;
    int i;
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for( i = 0; i< n ; i++)
    {
        res = max(recRodCut(arr,n) , arr[i]+recRodCut(arr,n-i));
    }

    return res;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a<b)?a:b;
}

int main()
{
    int value[] = {0,1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20,24,30};
    int result = recRodCut(value, 4);

    printf("The value is %d \n", result);
}
```

Comment: Voted to close as a typographical error. See @mtijanic's observation of infinite recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not seeing a segfault here, but I am seeing an unterminated recursion, which ends up in a stack overflow.

Consider how you are calling your `recRodCut()`:

```
recRodCut(value, 4);

// i = 0, first iteration:
    res = max(recRodCut(value, 4), value[0]+recRodCut(value, 4-0));
```

As you can see, you are always calling recRodCut with the same arguments. Which means it will never hit `if(n==0)` and bail early.

---

By the way, your `max()` function is actually a `min()` function :)